# Cannot Set AppCompat RadioButton Circle Color

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-appcompat

So I am trying to address the issue of my RadioButtons for both API > 21 and API < 21. I cannot seem to find a clear answer. I create RadioButtons programmatically:

```
public void addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, int numberOfAnswers) {
    mPollAnswerArrayList = new ArrayList<AppCompatRadioButton>();
    for (int i = (numberOfAnswers - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        Log.e("Number of Answers", "The number of answers is " + numberOfAnswers);
        int indexCreated = ((numberOfAnswers-1)-i);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.add((indexCreated), new AppCompatRadioButton((getActivity().getApplicationContext()),null,R.style.RadioButtonTeal));
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setId(indexCreated);
        String firebaseChild = String.valueOf(indexCreated+1);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setText(dataSnapshot.child(POLL_ANSWERS_LABEL).child(firebaseChild).child("Answer").getValue().toString());
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_button_answer_text_size));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setButtonTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        }
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setSupportButtonTintList(
                ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getActivity(),
                        R.drawable.single_choice_state_list));
        mParams.setMargins((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_left), 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_bottom));

////            radioButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionRed));
        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated), mParams);
    }
}
```

Here are my themes:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="RadioButtonTeal" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I simply want black RadioButtons, but the circles aren't even appearing on API > 21 and API < 21[image]